# Arcgis .NET Runtime WFS layer from Geoserver

Tags: arcgis, geoserver, web-feature-service

does Arcgis .net runtime include any classes to load data from WFS and display it as a layer? I have been reading documentation and cannot find any WFS support. [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Layers_FeatureLayer.htm) seems to work only with arcgis servers.

My current solution: Request Geoserver -> parse gml -> display it as GraphisLayer filled with SimpleMarkerSymbol. I dont think its optimal, is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WFS is not supported by the Runtime at this point. It is however on the roadmap, but I don't have any specific timeframe for it at this point.

Your current solution should work for now, but you might want to consider using FeatureCollection instead of GraphicsLayer, since it is better at rendering large amount of features with less memory load.

Answer (score 1):

WFS (read-only) will be supported in the upcoming 100.5 release of ArcGIS Runtime.